# Issue to get all hosted zone id of AWS ELB through Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-route53, amazon-elb

I have created two AWS NLBs in the same region through terraform. Now I have to make DNS records in Route53 with type alias.
But there are an error.

```
Error: [ERR]: Error building changeset: InvalidChangeBatch: [Tried to create an alias that targets 11111111111111111111111-xxxxxxxxxxxx.elb.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com., type A in zone ZHURV0000000, but the alias target name does not lie within the target zone] status code: 400, request id: 2xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

It was working fine, when I had only single NLB.
because, we need ELB zone id to make DNS entry with alias type. and both NLB has different zone ID. but terraform is providing only single zone id through below code.

```
data "aws_elb_hosted_zone_id" "main" {}
```

Im taking reference from below link:
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/elb_hosted_zone_id

The ultimate problem is:
How to get the 2nd, 3rd .. zone id of ELB in the same region ??

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as second and third zone id for elastic load balancing. There is one per region for everyone, in fact you can get the IDs from here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/elb.html.

You can reuse the same `data` block for multiple records. What will change is the domain name which is unique for each load balancer:

```
resource "aws_route53_record" "www" {
  ...
  type    = "A"

  alias {
    name    = aws_lb.my_network_load_balancer.dns_name # This changes based on load balancer
    zone_id = data.aws_elb_hosted_zone_id.main # The remains the same for each record 
  }
}
```

Update:

`data "aws_elb_hosted_zone_id" "main" {}` does not work with network load balancers. We can get the canoical hosted zone id by referencing an attribute of `aws_elb` resource: `aws_lb.my_network_load_balancer.zone_id`.

Comment: Thanks Ervin, it make sense to me..  but what if some ALB are already present on the same region. As there are different ZONE ID for ALB and NLB. How we will ensure to get NLB ID ( not ALB which are already created ) ?

Comment: one more thing "aws_elb_hosted_zone_id" is always provides the ALB zone ID, doesn’t work for NLB !!

Comment: I see, my mistake. You probably would want to use get the zone id from the load balancer resource itself: `aws_lb.my_network_load_balancer.zone_id` or just hard-code it into a local variable.

Comment: Thanks Ervin, that is what i did, and just posted my answer. the actual fix was bit complex as I have created NLB through helm. just posted the simplified version.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got below solution for NLB DNS entry:
Here, I'm fetching zone id from the NLB name.

Note:  **"aws_elb_hosted_zone_id"** will provide you zone id of the ALB, not NLB

```
  resource "aws_route53_zone" "this" {
  name = lower("${var.base_domain_name}")
}

#get DNS zone
data "aws_route53_zone" "this" {
  name = lower("${var.base_domain_name}")
  depends_on = [
  aws_route53_zone.this
]
}

data "aws_lb" "my_nlb" {
  name = "my-nlb"
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "nlb_dns" {
  zone_id = data.aws_route53_zone.this.zone_id
  name    = "my-nlb-dns"
  type    = "A"
  alias {
    name                   = "my_nlb-0000000.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com"
    zone_id                = data.aws_lb.my_nlb.zone_id  # this is the fix
    evaluate_target_health = true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the snippet how I do this:

```
data "aws_lb_hosted_zone_id" "route53_zone_id_nlb" {
  region = var.region
  load_balancer_type = "network"
}
resource "aws_route53_record" "route53_wildcard" {
  depends_on = [helm_release.nginx_ingress]
  zone_id = data.terraform_remote_state.aws_remote.outputs.domain_zone_id # Replace with your zone ID
  name    = "*.${var.domain}" # Replace with your subdomain, Note: not valid with "apex" domains, e.g. example.com
  type    = "A"
  alias {
    name                   = data.kubernetes_service.nginx_ingress.status.0.load_balancer.0.ingress.0.hostname
    zone_id                = data.aws_lb_hosted_zone_id.route53_zone_id_nlb.id
    evaluate_target_health = false
  }
}
```

Attention!

Don't mix **zone_id of LB** (it is static and differs between regions [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/elb.html) AWS document) and **zone_id of Route 53** zone itself.

Comment: Just wanted to point out that the current, "best" answer mentions that: "There is one per region for everyone, in fact you can get the IDs from here." So it sounds like you might be misreading / misunderstanding the problem description or this information was updated since then.